# Address Rewriting and Masquerading postfix

Tags: email, postfix, centos5

This is header of mail that i have received on my email ID:-achal.tomar58@gmail.com from mailchimp:

```
Return-Path: bounce-mc.us2_6034522.1358370-achal.tomar58=gmail.com@mail76.us2.mcsv.net>
Received: from mail76.us2.mcsv.net (mail76.us2.mcsv.net. [173.231.139.76])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id er6si2501863qab.62.2012.06.03.05.09.29;
        Sun, 03 Jun 2012 05:09:29 -0700 (PDT)
```

My query is how they add the Sent to: header to the Return-Path dynamically,i also want to implement the same in my mail server,i have tried address masquereading in postfix but it was not of much help may be i am misssing something.
My mail server has postfix as an MTA and i have centOs 5 as an OS.

Answer (score 2):

That format is called VERP.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path

This can either be generated by the sending application, or can be configured in MTA.